# How to streamline an SSRS web service call?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, tenfold

Using a 3rd party application (Tenfold) I currently call the SSRS web service methods to render a report as .pdf.

After I receive the encoded blob (5th parameter in the Render Method) I write the blob to the file system as a pdf using an internal WriteBinaryFile call, but in this form I cannot open it in a pdf reader. To solve this problem we write a .txt file with the path and file name of the pdf. Then send that to an external program Base64Decoder.exe which converts the file to a user friendly form that I can then open and view properly.

The Base64Decoder.exe is not 100% reliable and I'm looking for a better way to solve this problem. From what I've read from others the web service should return the blob in binary form which I then should be able to open without any conversion. Thanks in advance for any light that you can shed on this issue for me.

Comment: What language is your application in? In .NET you could do something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and convert the base64 string to a byte[] and stream the byte array back to the user.

Comment: The application is written in Tenfold which is a rapid application developing platform written in C#. If what you are saying is that the web service returns a string not a binary format, then that helps some. Thx

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you are doing. Could you post some sample code of what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, code is all behind the scenes, I receive the pdf blob from the web service and write it directly to the file system. Just curious about what others have done after receiving the blob from ssrs to make it viewable, if nothing is done by others then it's possible that the problem is with my tools and there is no better solution.

Answer (score 0):

the render method returns a byte array, which is what you want to save to disk

there's an example here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258532(v=sql.80).aspx